# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

...кто погиб на фронте(?) и чьи имена не удалось выяснить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо приводить фразу целиком. Вероятно, это у вас однородные придаточные – тогда запятая не нужна. Например: *Мы чтим память всех, кот погиб на фронте и чьи имена не удалось выяснить.*

Корявая у меня фраза получилась, но вы поняли.

Comment: Да, спасибо! Почти так и было